# Nginx try_files or else continue matching against locations?

Tags: nginx

I'm wondering whether this is possible with Nginx: I just added a directory with a bunch of HTML files (foo.html, bar.html) that I'd like to serve with /foo, /bar, etc.  If the URL doesn't match up with a file name I'd like to fall back to whatever the next best matching `location` would be.

So I have:

```
  # This block is newly added.
  location ~ ^/([^/]+)$ {
    default_type text/html;
    alias /blah/$1.html;
  }

  # Our long list of existing subsystems below....
  location /subscribe {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
  }

  location /upload {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8090;
    proxy_read_timeout 99999;
  }

  location ~ /(data|garbage|blargh).* {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8090;
    proxy_read_timeout 99999;
    auth_basic text;
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd;
  }

  ....
```

The problem is that the first regex now eats up the URLs that would've gone to other `location`s, as per the documented behavior of `location`.

One approach is to maintain the full explicit list of files in the first `location` block, but this list is quite large and is always changing.  Is there a way to check to see if the file exists first, and if not, then continue with what would've been the next-best `location` match?

I took stabs using `try_files` (including using a @fallback and nesting `location`s in there) but I don't think it's capable of doing this.  However I thought I'd ask here in case I'm missing something.  (Or maybe there's another better approach altogether.)

Answer (score 1):

`location /` has the lowest priority anyway, so I'd use `try_files` and this trick:

```
    root /ngx/html/s;
    location / {
        try_files $uri.html /s$uri;
    }
    location /s {
        internal;
        root /ngx/html;
    }
```